# How to download barcode labels in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have bar codes stored in database and I want to allow user to download the label of bar code for his products. How can I convert the number e.g 5036040142375 to image of barcode and user get print out of labels.

Comment: I'm not in c# but when I google for "c# create barcode" there are several links to sides where this is shown.

Comment: Here is a good step by step guide to create barcodes saved in the database, right according to your requirement - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/749557/Generate-Bar-Code-Using-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Why you all are miss understanding my question. My question is i have generated bar code and all are saved in database only the issue is to display there image and download them.

Comment: Understood, can you please post the code how you generated the barcode? So that other may well understand your question and then can offer their help? There are many ways to generate the barcode and It depends how you generated it, like is it being generated in memory byte[] or exported in a file? We need to see first.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this barcode generation library - http://www.barcodelib.com/

And following is the code to generate the barcode, I am posting the barcode generation code again, because in my code you can see that the barcode generation process is generating a PNG image which you can save and then use to do what ever you like, like display or provide as download to users etc -

```
        /// <summary>
        /// This method is used to generate the Bar Code for the Item
        /// </summary>
        private static string GenerateBarCode(string path, string code)
        {
            BarcodeLib.Barcode b = new BarcodeLib.Barcode(code, BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE39);
            Image img = b.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE39, code, 300, 50);
            string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + code + ".png";
            b.SaveImage(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path + "/" + filename), BarcodeLib.SaveTypes.PNG);
            return filename;
        }
```

Comment: I also have used this library and It works very well :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
namespace BarCode.Models
    {
        public class barcodecs
        {
            public string generateBarcode()
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] charPool = "1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0".Split('-');
                    StringBuilder rs = new StringBuilder();
                    int length = 6;
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    while (length-- > 0)
                    {
                        int index = (int)(rnd.NextDouble() * charPool.Length);
                        if (charPool[index] != "-")
                        {
                            rs.Append(charPool[index]);
                            charPool[index] = "-";
                        }
                        else
                            length++;
                    }
                    return rs.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //ErrorLog.WriteErrorLog("Barcode", ex.ToString(), ex.Message);
                }
                return "";
            }

            public Byte[] getBarcodeImage(string barcode, string file)
            {
                try
                {
                    BarCode39 _barcode = new BarCode39();
                    int barSize = 16;
                    string fontFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/fonts/FREE3OF9.TTF");
                    return (_barcode.Code39(barcode, barSize, true, file, fontFile));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //ErrorLog.WriteErrorLog("Barcode", ex.ToString(), ex.Message);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

For more information use this [Generate Bar Code Using ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/749557/Generate-Bar-Code-Using-ASP-NET-MVC)

and

[Generating Barcode in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/krishnasarala/generating-barcode-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: that is for generating bar code. I have already generated.. but the issue is i want to display the bar code image and then download